# coercing argument is not an atomic vector (repeating endlessly)

Tags: r

Newbie question here. I'm trying to run some code that will extract the usernames and dates from a list of assembled web pages. This was working perfectly fine before, but now when I run the code I keep getting the error "coercingargument is not an atomic vector" which repeats endlessly.

I've tried reviewing previous answers here but nothing seemed to quite work. I can't understand why it suddenly stopped working even though nothing has changed. My feeling is I either removed a library it needed or something hasn't quite reset. Any help would be warmly appreciated.

```
# COLLECT THE DATES
for (i in urls3) {
  addurl <- i
  discussion <- read_html(i, timeout = 1000000000)
  usernames <- discussion %>% 
  html_nodes(".lia-component-message-view-widget-author-username a") %>% 
  html_text()
  all.usernames <- append(all.usernames, usernames)
  datetime <- discussion %>% 
  html_nodes(".local-friendly-date")
  datetime <- str_extract(datetime, "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2}")
  datetime <- parse_date_time(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%p", tz = "US/Eastern")
  datetime <- as.character(datetime)
  date.posted <- datetime[1]
  date.replied <- datetime[2]
  date.difference <- difftime(datetime[2],datetime[1], units=c("mins"))

  new.table <- rbind(new.table,c(addurl, date.posted, date.replied, date.difference))
}
```

The expected results would be a table with the URL, date posted, date replied, and date difference.

The actual results are "argument is not an atomic vector; coercingargument is not an atomic vector; coercingargument is not an atomic vector; coercingargument is not an atomic vector; ..."

Comment: What is urls3 ?

Comment: It’s a list of urls scraped from an online community stored as strings.

Comment: Could you give a sample exemple ?

Comment: [1] "https://community.spotify.com/t5/Music-Chat/View-Each-Other-s-Playlists-Music-For-Men-In-Love/m-p/4769051"                                  
   [2] "https://community.spotify.com/t5/Music-Chat/My-Song-of-the-Week-Kaiser-Chiefs-People-Know-How-To-Love-One/m-p/4769048"                      
   [3] "https://community.spotify.com/t5/Music-Chat/Mr-Groove/m-p/4769045"

Comment: You're welcome, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need these packages to make your code work :

```
library(textreadr)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
```

You could ckeck where in the for loop it is bugging and last be careful when you concatenate to have the same object in the two sides.

```
append, c, rbind
```

You have two package with `read_html` function be careful. You will gained clearness to give a more syntetic example. I hope it will help you.

Comment: ah, that's interesting. Do you know which two packages have the read_html function? I'm sure rvest does. What's the other?

Comment: A little, oddly enough when I try copy and pasting the code into another .Rmd it seems to vanish by itself. I'm at a loss how to explain that at this point.